# Stata collapse translated to R

Tags: r, regression, grouping, stata, replication

I am trying to replicate some regression analysis in R which has been written in Stata. I have very basic knowledge of Stata syntax so I am struggling to translate some commands. The commands are:

```
collapse (max) varA (mean) VarB one two three four five $noise_basic_collapse r_wk, by(city id sic  after)
replace year=int(year)
replace lemp=-99 if emp==.
cap drop lempm
gen lempm=lemp==-99
```

The macro has been defined like this:

```
global noise_basic_collapse         " p   rel ww* aa*"
```

So far I only could get behind the idea that some variables decribed in the example are collapsed with means and maximum functions. But my main problem is rather how (groups, which variables exactly).

Comment: The pattern is that `collapse (max) foo (mean) bar bazz, by(group1 group2)` produces a reduced dataset with the maximum of `foo` and the means of `bar bazz` according to the distinct values of `group1 group2`.

Comment: The last few commands are a roundabout way to indicate a missing indicator for `emp` and could be condensed to `gen lempm = missing(emp)` (except that `replace` not `gen` is needed if `lempm` already exists).

Comment: I've used Stata a lot but R only occasionally so I can't offer a translation. It is always more direct and often more successful to say what you want to do in R, so long as you try some code as well. Wanting translation depends on readers being fluent in both languages. In any case even a fluent R user might want to see a simplified and complete reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with `data.table`, this website which is designed for Stata users learning R might be useful to you. It has a section on `collapse`: https://stata2r.github.io/data.table/#collapse

In terms of an explanation myself, I don't think I can improve on what Nick Cox provided. Perhaps I'll just add that the macro means that a variable called `p` (or maybe just starting with `p`, if only one variable starts with `p`) and `rel` (or similarly maybe the only variable which starts with `rel`) and all variables starting with `aa` and `ww` are also replaced in the new dataset with their means by a group defined by the unique combinations of `city` `id` `sic`  `after`